# C++ STL vector iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, stl, vector

```
// Erase the missing items
vector<AlignedFDRData>::size_type StandardNum = FDRFreq.at(0).fData.size();
vector<AlignedFDRData>::iterator iter = FDRFreq.begin(); 
while (iter != FDRFreq.end()){
    if( iter->fData.size() < StandardNum){
        FDRFreq.erase(iter);
    }
    else{
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

This part is used to erase the FDRFreq vector item, in which the data length is smaller than the standard number, but the debug assertion failed: vector iterators incompatible. I am a green hand in C++ STL, thanks for your kindly help.

Comment: You invalidate your iterator if you `erase`, think about it. you should store the iterator that is returned from the call to erase like Mahmoud has answered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code needs to become

```
while (iter != FDRFreq.end()){
    if( iter->fData.size() < StandardNum){
        iter = FDRFreq.erase(iter);
    }
    else{
        ++iter;
    }
}
```

"vector iterators incompatible" means that the iterator you're using has been invalidated - that is to say, there is no guarantee that the elements it points to still exist at that memory location. An erase of a vector element invalidates the iterators following that location. `.erase` returns a new, valid iterator you can use instead.

If you're new to STL, I highly recommend you read Scott Myer's *Effective STL* (and *Effective C++*, while you're at it)

Comment: This is not the idiomatic way for a reason. It will trigger as much reallocation and copies as elements are going to be removed. Don't use it.

Comment: Yes, but that is the correct answer to the question the OP asked. I added the recommendation to read Effective STL which provides the correct method.

Comment: Point taken. Still, I don't think a reference to a single book is helpful here. OP is not going to find the information he immediately needs and his code will continue to be wrong (Yes, I consider horrible performance to be wrong code).

Comment: Thanks for all of you. I will read the book recommended here^^.

Comment: It's not really a book, it's 25 "correct ways" of doing things. Very short, you don't have to read in order, and very to the point.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is iterator invalidation after the call to `std::erase`. The warning is triggered by an iterator debugging extensions in your standard library implementation. `erase` returns an iterator to the new valid location after the erase element and you continue iterating from there. However, this is still very inefficient.

Use the [Erase-Remove Idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) to remove data with a predicate from a `vector`.

```
FDRFreq.erase(std::remove_if(
                begin(FDRFreq), end(FDRFreq), 
                [&StandardNum](const AlignedFDRData& x) { 
                  return fData.size() > StandardNum; }),
              end(FDRFreq));
```

Comment: Your revised answer with an explanation, links, and the correct code is now more correct than mine.